# undefined reference to protector::Winner::Winner()

Tags: c++, linux, ооп, g++, makefile

Я пишу программу, которая прекрасно работала в Dev C++ и Visual Studio, а на компиляции в linux терминале полетела с указанными ошибками. Компилирую через makefile:

```
### settings
CC = g++
FLAGS = -Wall
OBJ = Maze.o Way.o Player.o
HEADERS = Maze.h Way.h Player.h

### run the main executable
run : main.exe

### run the unit tests
test : Test.exe

### clean build from source
rebuild : clean build

### build executables
build : main.exe Test.exe

### set debug flag, rebuild and run unit tests
debug : FLAGS += -DDEBUG
debug : clean Test.exe

### executables
main.exe : main.cpp ${OBJ} ${HEADERS}
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.cpp $(OBJ) -o main.exe  
test.exe : test.cpp $(OBJ) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) Test.cpp $(OBJ) -o Test.exe

### object files for the classes         
Player.o : Player.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c Player.cpp -o Player.o
Maze.o : Maze.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c Maze.cpp -o Maze.o
Way.o : Way.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c Way.cpp -o Way.o

### clean all executables and object files
clean :
    rm -f *.exe *.o
```

P.S. В моей проге 2 maina (обычный и для класса Test), в Deve я второй просто комментирую. Но ошибки выскакивают для основного maina (не тестового).

> g++ -Wall main.cpp Maze.o Way.o Player.o -o main.exe   /tmp/ccalG046.o:
>   In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to`
>   protector::Winner::Winner()' main.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined
>   reference to `protector::Winner::addWinner(protector::Player const&)'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to`
>   protector::Generator::Generator()' main.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined
>   reference to `protector::Generator::~Generator()'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to`
>   protector::Winner::~Winner()' main.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined
>   reference to `protector::Winner::~Winner()' Way.o: In function`
>   protector::Way::wasInjured(protector::Player*, protector::Monster)':
>   Way.cpp:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to
>   `protector::Monster::getLethalArea()' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status makefile:25: recipe for target 'main.exe' failed make: ***
>   [main.exe] Error 1

Если makefile тут не при чем, подскажите пожалуйста, что именно компилятору может не нравится в конструкторах, деструкторах и подобной подаче аргументов? Буду исправлять код.

Comment: Ну так пишет же: `undefined reference to ...`. Ищите где эти методы у вас описаны, и не выключаются ли они какими-нибудь директивами препроцессора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глупая ошибка. Не включила некоторые классы в makefile. Топик можно считать закрытым.

Comment: если ошибка глупая, и вопрос не будет полезен другим участникам, то может быть Вам стоит удалить вопрос? или же отметьте Ваш ответ как решение(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа).

Comment: @Alex Вы правы, спасибо :)